# Worldpay lightbox Integration

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, worldpay

I am trying to do the Worldpay lightbox integration as [explained here](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/hpp/Content/Content4/Code%20for%20example%20webpages.htm)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customOptions = {
        iframeIntegrationId: 'libraryObject',
        iframeHelperURL: 'https://example.com/helper.html',
        iframeBaseURL: 'https://example.com',
        url: 'https://payments.worldpay.com/ngpp/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=YOUR_ORDER_KEY&Ticket=YOUR_TICKET_ID',
        type: 'iframe',
        target: 'custom-html',
        accessibility: true,
        debug: false,
        language: 'en',
        country: 'gb',
        preferredPaymentMethod: 'VISA-SSL',
        successURL: 'https://example.com/success',
        cancelURL: 'https://example.com/cancel',
        failureURL: 'https://example.com/failure',
        pendingURL: 'https://example.com/pending',
        errorURL: 'https://example.com/error'
    };
    //initialise the library and pass options
    var libraryObject = new WPCL.Library();
    libraryObject.setup(customOptions);
</script>
```

By using this script the url shows 404 error.Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you need to replace YOUR_ORDER_KEY with your order key and YOUR_TICKET_ID with your ticket ID.

Comment: Where to get ticket_id

Comment: I have no idea.  Perhaps you need to register for one somewhere on the worldpay site.

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this problem, based upon the same code provided by Worldpay. The issue is caused simply because the libraryObject is being instantiated before the DOM is loaded - the Worldpay JavaScript attempts to inject its iFrame into the target 'custom-html' which doesn't exist. All you need to do is move the object instantiation within a ready function to ensure the DOM has loaded before you try to access it, e.g.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // initialise the library and pass options
        var libraryObject = new WPCL.Library();
        libraryObject.setup(customOptions);
    });
```

It might help if you change the debug setting to true - note that the debug is written to the browser console output rather than Visual Studio's!