# Worldpay Javascript API Hosted Integration in lightbox/iframe does not work

Tags: javascript, iframe, worldpay

I am trying to integrate a Worldpay order page in a lightbox/iframe on a client site.

Step 1. As per https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/hosted-payment-pages I make the HTTP request via PHP/CURL, and get a valid response with the orderCode and RedirectURL values etc.
The docs say "The URL value in the redirectUrl attribute response is the URL of the Hosted Payment Page. That is where you need to redirect the shopper."
The url is of the format https://online.worldpay.com/simulators/hpp?orderCode=xxx&merchantId=xxx&country=GB&language=en
Opening this URL in a browser gives a Worldpay payment page as expected.

Step 2. As per https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/hosted-advanced-usage which says "Once you have received the redirect URL following the example on the Hosted Payments page, use this to populate the url field in the iframe configuration JavaScript outlined below."
I have set the integration page up **exactly** as per https://payments.worldpay.com/resources/hpp/integrations/embedded/doc/ using the redirectURL value in the javascript object, and can not get the lightbox/iframe to appear. I have tried both lightbox and iframe methods, on the client domain and also set up a test page on a different domain using the sample code exactly as provided by Worldpay, this didn't work either.

Possible issue: looking at the WP javascript library it seems that the URL is being rewritten to: https://online.worldpay.com/simulators/hpp-iframe/?orderCode=xxx&merchantId=xxx&country=GB&language=en, regardless if the lightbox or iframe type is chosen:

```
    // Use iframe app instead
    url = url.replace("/hpp/", "/hpp-iframe/");
```

This does't appear to be a valid URL, if opened it immediately redirects to the worldpay homepage. Forcing it to keep the original URL **does** get the lightbox/iframe to open, however it does not resize to fit the remote content.

A further complication: the example URLs given in the WP docs are 'https://payments.worldpay.com/ngpp/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=YOUR_ORDER_KEY&Ticket=YOUR_TICKET_ID'
and
'https://payments-test.worldpay.com/app/hpp/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=xxx&Ticket=xxx'
which are different to the one actually returned - also there is no explanation of 'TICKET_ID' anywhere.

Has anyone managed to get a working, resizing Worldpay lightbox/iframe integration using this method? I've been struggling with this for days (Worldpay's documentation is insanely bad)

Comment: I'm finding your description a little hard to follow, but could it be a timing / page life-cycle issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265264/worldpay-lightbox-integration/40179296#40179296. If you could paste some code that would help.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that and tried it, but it didn't help. I've abandoned this approach now and gone back to the old static HTML form. I honestly don't believe the lightbox functionality actually works. Even Worldpay tech support were unable to shed any light on the issues I was having.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I was able to implement Worldpay's Hosted Payments iFrame solution - although it was painful because their documentation isn't good and their technical support guy was more of a hindrance than a help! If you decide to try again please post your code and I'll happily take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this 4 years after the OP query, but may be of help to subsequent readers.... We have been through this recently (2022) and the answer is that the URL to the WP Hosted Payment Page that is returned from the WP Order Request API cannot be used "as is" (i.e. directly), it needs to be first run though a WP Javascript SDK library function to turn it into a URL that can then be used by your lightbox/iframe.

Comment: Got this in the S/O review queue & I don't even know the context, but thank you for sharing this even after finding this 4 years too late for the OP! <3